# ng-pattern for only numbers will accept chars like '-' in angular.js

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

pattern to make an input text accept only numbers between 0-9.

this is my pattern:

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /[\u0030-\u0039]+/g;
```

for some reason,
chars like '-' will be accepted even though it is not in the range i have declared.

this is my input html:

```
  <input style="width:40%;" type="text" name="phone" ng-minlength="10" ng-maxlength="15" ng-model="register.phone" placeholder='cell phone' ng-pattern="onlyNumbers" required title="please enter cell phone">
```

can someone help please?

Comment: Did you try escaping the `-` with a backslash?

Comment: @FooL OP wants to exclude the `-`—that's the issue.

Comment: Is there a practical reason why you're using a unicode range instead of a literal range (`[0-9]` or `\d`)?

Answer (score 41):

To make it simpler `\d` = any numeric value

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^\d+$/;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/JPkER/1/

Answer (score 13):

You need to anchor the expression to restrict the value to numbers only and I don't think you need the global modifier so you expression should become:

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[\u0030-\u0039]+$/;
```

And even a better expression:

```
$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
```

Comment: @Rantiev Can't be, but be careful as your expression matches empty string as well.

Comment: There were bug in my code above, removed it to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Try this for greater than 0 numbers:
`$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[1-9]+[0-9]*$/`

For any numbers: `$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[0-9]+$/'

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the regx pattern

$scope.onlyNumbers = /^[0-9]{1,7}$/;